# How to duplicate one directory/folder and its contents 100 times?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

I need to know how to make 100 copies of the same folder and its sub-folders.

I know how to copy once with the following:

`for /l %i in (1,1,1) do xcopy /i /e "folder 1" "folder 2"`

Is there a way to make this code run 100 times and make 100 copies of folder 1 and its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try to increase the **`%L`** variable in your **`for /L`** loop, from **`1,1,1`** to **`1,1,100`**...

- In command line:

```cmd
for /L %L in (1,1,100)do %__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe /i /e "folder 1" "folder %L"
```

---

- In **[bat](/questions/tagged/bat)/[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)** file: :

```cmd
@echo off && for /L %%L in (1,1,100)do %__APPDIR__%xcopy.exe /i /e "folder 1" "folder %%L"
```

---

```
your cmd:  (     1,        1,     1 ) == 1, 1, 1 
    loop:  ( start, increase, until ) == x,+1, y
you need:  (     1,        1,   100 ) == 1, 1, 100
```

- Take a time to read: [For /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)